# How can I get 2 textboxes to change value based on dropdown menu selection?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm writing javascript if statements that change the value inside of textboxes based on dropdown selection.  I have 2 textbox fields and 2 Dropdown menus.

DDB and DDA are my dropdown menu ids.
TextBox1 and TextBox2 are my textbox ids.

The code I currently have works, except the value in TextBox1 always stays on -90.4567 regardless of my selection.  On the otherhand, TextBox2 changes based on my dropdown selection and works perfectly.

Anything wrong in my javascript code that's causing TextBox2 to stay constant on -90.4567?

```
<script>
function Blah(value) {
var test = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>");
var test2 = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox2.ClientID %>");
var ddlB = document.getElementById("<%=DDB.ClientID %>");
var ddlA = document.getElementById("<%=DDA.ClientID %>");

if (ddlB.value == "10.1" && ddlA.value == "Inside") { test2.value = '10.1234' } { test.value = '-90.1234' }
if (ddlB.value == "10.2" && ddlA.value == "Inside") { test2.value = '20.1234' } { test.value = '-90.2345' }
if (ddlB.value == "10.3") { test2.value = '30.1234' } { test.value = '-90.3456' }
if (ddlB.value == "10.4") { test2.value = '40.1234' } { test.value = '-90.4567' }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need an `if` to execute multiple lines of code, they all must be wrapped in a single block like so:

```
if (condition) {
   //multiple lines of code
}
```

By doing it your way, the second block is *always* going to execute, regardless of the condition. Because `test.value = '-90.4567'` is last, that's what it will end up being set to.

Check out this example, and notice how the second block is **always** executed:

```js
if (false) {console.log("true")} {console.log("false")}
```

Your conditions should probably look more like this, although admittedly they could afford to be cleaned up using some `else if`s.

```
if (ddlB.value == "10.1" && ddlA.value == "Inside") { 
    test2.value = '10.1234';
    test.value = '-90.1234';
}

if (ddlB.value == "10.2" && ddlA.value == "Inside") { 
    test2.value = '20.1234';
    test.value = '-90.2345';
}

if (ddlB.value == "10.3") {
    test2.value = '30.1234';
    test.value = '-90.3456';
}

if (ddlB.value == "10.4") { 
    test2.value = '40.1234';
    test.value = '-90.4567' }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the onchange event on the dropdown list with jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
            if($(this).val() == $VALOR1){
                // Código para valor 1             
         }else{
                //Código para valor 2
         }
});
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answer has any relation to OP's question. He says that one of the conditions hits based on the dropdown, so it's assumed that his function `Blah` is attached already. Your code references checkboxes (which aren't even included in the question). There are undefined references to something called `$VALOR1`. And, OP never mentioned jQuery or tagged it in his question, so providing an answer that's strictly jQuery is probably not the best solution.